# Why symbolic variable usage takes time in matlab? How to remove it?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have the following code.

```
syms x y; % line 1

%solve them for the parabola equation
 A  = [ x^2 x y 1 ;x0^2 x0 y0 1; x1^2 x1 y1 1; x2^2 x2 y2 1];  %line 2
 S = solve(det(A),y); %line 3
```

**(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)**  are integer coordinates.

The line 2 takes 0.48 seconds for 73 calls and the line 3 takes 1.5 seconds for 73 calls.

In **line 2** I am only defining a matrix.
Why is time so much in line 1?

Also any suggestions on decreasing the time?

Thanks

Comment: I almost find it more interesting that line 2 is taking 1.5 seconds lol...something seems a bit off for the timing for both lines, not just line 1

Comment: Sorry, but I mistakenly written wrong line number. Corrected it.

Comment: @t0mkaka Why are you repeating line #2 73 times?

Comment: Its in a for loop. I am writing code for the randomized hough transform.